# WP All Import Pro Function To Change Date And Time Format (From Imported .CSV)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, datetime

I have a .csv file which I import in my WordPress website using WP All Import Pro.
Everything works fine but since I need the date to be in a different format then it comes in the .csv, and seperate the time from the date, and the date from the time I was wondering how to do this.

```
Example:
**08/11/2020 17:14** (OLD DATE & TIME; FROM .CSV) ( **{pick_up_time[1]}** )

2020-11-08 17:14:00 (NEW DATE & TIME; BASED ON THE OLD DATE & TIME)
2020-11-08 (NEW DATE ONLY; BASED ON THE OLD DATE & TIME)
17:14:00 (NEW TIME ONLY; BASED ON THE OLD DATE & TIME)

It is possible to use functions in the function editor in the import set up.

I want to use the data in custom fields;

end_datetime: {pick_up_time[1]} (2020-11-08 17:14:00)
end_date: {pick_up_time[1]} (2020-11-08)
end_time: {pick_up_time[1]} (17:14:00)
```

I'm not an expert in php, but I'm willing to learn. Someone who can steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my own question.
You can use Strtotime and echo it as date. It wil convert the date as needed.

```
[date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( {pick_up_time[1]} ) )]
[date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( {pick_up_time[1]} ) )]
[date( "H:i", strtotime( {pick_up_time[1]} ) )]
```

**Edit:**
Must replace string when using strtotime with date. 08/11/2020 17:14 (has /)

Should be:

```
[date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( str_replace("/",".",{pick_up_time[1]}) ) )]
[date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( str_replace("/",".",{pick_up_time[1]}) ) )]
[date( "H:i:s", strtotime( str_replace("/",".",{pick_up_time[1]}) ) )]
```

For the correct format.

Comment: date strings with a slash `/` are interpreted as US dates (mm/dd/YYYY), whereas dots `.` and hyphens are used in other locales (Germany, UK - generally day first). see eg https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this to change the format of the imported date:

In the wpallimport functions section, add this:

```
// Date manipulation
  function my_fix_date( $date, $format = 'Ymd', $new_format = 'Y/m/d' ) {
   if ( $obj = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, $date ) ) {
    return $obj->format( $new_format ); 
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

And then in the actual "published date" field, enter this:

Example usage:

```
[my_fix_date({date[1]},"d/m/Y","Y-m-d")]
```

info from here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-date-format-64/

Answer (score 0):

Another option in WPAllImport for me was to use the standard options and to go to "Other Post Options". Look for "Post Dates" > "As specified" then drag and drop the Date field. See the image below:

[{date[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yhH0.png)} goes here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yhH0.png)